# using DOMPDF to get PDF with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dompdf

First of all sorry for my English.

I'm trying to create a pdf with a portion of html, using jQuery, Ajax and DomPDF.

In my server side I use the next code:

```
require_once './dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
if(!empty($_GET['pdf'])){
    $html=$_GET['pdf'];

    # Instanciamos un objeto de la clase DOMPDF.
    $mipdf =  new Dompdf();

    # Definimos el tamaño y orientación del papel que queremos.
    # O por defecto cogerá el que está en el fichero de configuración.
    $mipdf ->setPaper("A4", "portrait");

    # Cargamos el contenido HTML.
    $mipdf ->loadHtml(utf8_decode($html));

    # Renderizamos el documento PDF.
    $mipdf ->render();

    # Enviamos el fichero PDF al navegador.
    //$mipdf ->stream("Claustro.pdf");
    echo base64_encode($mipdf->output());
}
```

In client side, in jQuery I have:

```
$("#imprimir").click(function(){
  console.log(datos);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'text',
    url: "./librerias/php/funciones.php",
    data: {pdf:datos},
    success: function(pdf) {
      var modalWidth = $(window).width() - 400;
      var modalHeight = $(window).height() - 400
      var iframeWidth = modalWidth - 20;
      var iframeHeight = modalHeight - 20;
      $( "#display_dialog").html('<iframe width="' + iframeWidth + '" height="' + iframeHeight + '" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdf + '"></object>');
      $( "#display_dialog" ).dialog({
        width: modalWidth,
        height: modalHeight,

        modal: true,
        close: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#display_dialog").html("");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});//fin imprimir
```

I have all html code in var "datos" I want in pdf.

To show the iframe I have an hidden div:

```
<div id="display_dialog"></div>
```

but I can't get the PDF, The iframe works but no data.

any solution? can anybody help me? thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

To solve de the problem I made some changes:

In server side:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'PDFs/');
if(!empty($_POST['pdf'])){

    $html=$_POST['pdf'];
    @file_put_contents("texto.txt", $html);
    $name=str_replace(" ","+",$_POST['nombre']);
    $nombre = $name;

        # Instanciamos un objeto de la clase DOMPDF.
    $options = new Options();
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

    $mipdf =  new Dompdf($options);

        # Definimos el tamaño y orientación del papel que queremos.
        # O por defecto cogerá el que está en el fichero de configuración.
    $mipdf ->setPaper("A4", "portrait");

        # Cargamos el contenido HTML.
    $mipdf ->loadHtml(utf8_decode($html));

        # Renderizamos el documento PDF.
    $mipdf ->render();

        # Enviamos el fichero PDF al navegador.
        //$mipdf ->stream("Claustro.pdf");
    $pdf=$mipdf->output();
    @file_put_contents(UPLOAD_DIR.$nombre.".pdf", $pdf);
    echo json_encode("http://regorodri.noip.me/proyecto/librerias/php/".UPLOAD_DIR.$nombre.".pdf");
    //}
}
```

In client side:

```
$("#imprimir").click(function(){
  var name=$("#day").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'text',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "./librerias/php/funciones.php",
    data: {pdf:datos,nombre:name},
    success: function(pdf) {
      console.log("url->",pdf);
      window.open(pdf, '_blank');
    }
  });
```